# How to create pages in keystone.js from admin section

Tags: node.js, model, keystonejs

i am new to node.js as well as keystone.
i want to create new model called pages same as post which is default from keystone.

new model which i create is code as

```
var pages = new keystone.List('pages', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true }
});

pages.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'draft, published, archived', default: 'published', index: true },
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', index: true },
    publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true, dependsOn: { state: 'published' } },
    image: { type: Types.LocalFile, dest: 'public/uploads'},
    content: {
        brief: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 150 },
        extended: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 }
    },
});

pages.schema.virtual('content.full').get(function() {
    return this.content.extended || this.content.brief;
});

pages.defaultColumns = 'title, state|20%, author|20%, publishedDate|20%';
pages.register();
```

then i created a route for pages

```
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
        locals = res.locals;

    // Init locals
    locals.section = 'pages';
    locals.data = {
        pages: []
    };

    // Load the pages
    view.on('init', function(next) {

        var q = keystone.list('pages').paginate({
                page: req.query.page || 1,
                perPage: 10,
                maxPages: 10
            })
            .where('state', 'published')
            .sort('-publishedDate');
        q.exec(function(err, results) {
            locals.data.pages = results;
            next(err);
        });

    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('pages');
};
```

also created middleware

```
{ label: 'pages',       key: 'pages',       href: '/pages' }
```

this all i have done to create model....let me know what i am missing.
when i call this from pages.jade file by follow code:

```
data.pages.title
```

this shows me nothing. Even not showing any error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `results` from the `q.exec()` callback is an array, which you assign to `local.data.pages`. Therefore `data.pages` in your Jade template is an array and `data.pages.title` would be `null`.

You'll need to iterate over the returned pages. The example below will render the page titles, assuming the returned array of results is not empty.

```
each page in data.pages
  p= page.title
```